# Grouping string to list of strings

Tags: python, strings

The following is function that I have written to group a string to groups, based on whether there's consecutive repeated occurrence. Fop example `AAAABBBBAAB` is grouped as `[A+,B+,A+,B]`. Is it possible to make below code more pythonic?  If yes, how?

```
def create_groups(alphabets):
    """ function group the alphabets to list of A(+)s and B(+)s """
    index = 1
    current = alphabets[0]
    count = 0
    groups = []
    accumulate = False
    while index < len(alphabets):
        if current == alphabets[index]:
            count += 1
            accumulate = True
        else:
            accumulate = False
        if accumulate == False or index == len(alphabets)-1:
            group_indicator = current + '+' if count > 0 else current
            groups.append(group_indicator)
            current = alphabets[index]
            count = 0
        index += 1
    return groups
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your method is not really correct: for `AAAABBBBAAB` it returns `[A+, B+, A+]` instead of the required `[A+, B+, A+, B]`. That's because the last group is never added to the list of groups.

This is not very Pythonic:

> ```
> if accumulate == False:
> ```

Write it this way instead:

```
if not accumulate:
```

Also, instead of iterating over the "alphabet" using indexes, it would be more Pythonic to rewrite to iterate over each letter, in the style `for letter in alphabet`.

"alphabets" is not a good name. It seems `letters` would be better.

The algorithm can be simplified, and you could eliminate several intermediary variables:

```
def create_groups(letters):
    """ function group the alphabets to list of A(+)s and B(+)s """
    prev = letters[0]
    count = 0
    groups = []
    for current in letters[1:] + '\0':
        if current == prev:
            count += 1
        else:
            group_indicator = prev + '+' if count > 0 else prev
            groups.append(group_indicator)
            count = 0
        prev = current
    return groups
```

In the `for` loop, I appended `'\0'` to the end, as a dirty trick to make the loop do one more iteration to append the last letter group to `groups`. For this to work, it must be a character that's different from the last letter in `letters`.

---

The above is sort of a "naive" solution, in the sense that probably there is a Python library that can do this easier. Kinda like what [@jonrsharpe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32391/jonrsharpe) suggested, but he didn't complete the solution of converting `[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'A'], ['B']]` in the format that you need. Based on his solution, you could do something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby


def create_groups(letters):
    return [x + '+' if list(g)[1:] else x for x, g in groupby(letters, str)]
```

What I don't like about this is the way we put the letters in a list just to know if there are 2 or more of them (the `list(g)[1:]` step). There might be a better way.

Comment: *"he didn't complete the solution"* - this isn't a code-writing service, I thought I'd let the OP have some of the fun!

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your logic significantly using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for _, g in groupby("AAAABBBBAAB")]
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'A'], ['B']]
```

Comment: `ord` is unnecessary here: "If not specified, `key` defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged."

Comment: @GarethRees ah, I'd read that as meaning `id`. Edited, thanks.